# Which Activity to send a warning after X days, then a "You're Late email?

Tags: asp.net, workflow, asp.net-3.5, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

Full explanation. I currently have a Listen Activity with 3 branches. First branch is if the document is returned on time. Second is if after X days has passed the user gets an email warning them not to be late. Third branch is after Y days the document is late and the user gets an email stating that the document is late. The listen activity is within a while loop. Now the way I have it set up, I know that the workflow is going to execute the second branch every X days. I'm not quite sure how to set up the workflow so it execute the second branch, then if the document is still not returned, it will execute the third branch.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Windows Server AppFabric / Workflow Services Demo - Contoso HR](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WF4ContosoHR/) sample application.  It does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I ended up with 3 While Activities and a Listen in each While Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pick activity as it will only execute one of the branches when its condition is matched and cancel the other branches. You can then use a delay to wait the period of time appropriate for the branch action.

Comment: I"m using WF 3.5. It doesn't have a pick activity.

Comment: Well I found out that Pick in WF4 is Listen in WF3.5.